# SAS N Function in Stata

Tags: stata

Is there a function in Stata equivalent to the SAS `N()` function?

For example, in SAS, 
`N(of a1-a10)` should result in the count of variables of `a1` to `a10` with nonmissing values.

Comment: I don't know SAS at all. Does `of` appear in the syntax? Seems unlikely, but I've not edited it out.

Comment: You've been downvoted several times here. I wasn't  a downvoter, but I guess wildly that lack of research effort may have been a reason: there is no obvious evidence here for search of the documentation on Stata and certainly no attempt at code. In your interests (and mine!) I point out that accepting my answer would enable you to claw back some reputation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `egen` functions `count()` and `rownonmiss()` produce counts of non-missing values in new variables, the first working column-wise (e.g. on variables) and the second operating row-wise (across variables within observations).

Many commands report on missings in various ways, e.g. `codebook`, `inspect` and `missings` (SSC), on one or several variables at a time. On the last, see (e.g.) [this forum post](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1308777-missings-now-available-from-ssc-new-program-for-managing-missings). For the others, see help and manual entries as usual, which are also visible over the internet, e.g. [the help for codebook](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?codebook).

How to find this out: Note that `search missing` would have pointed to `egen` (and much else too, which can't easily be helped).

Comment: Thanks a lot. the rownonmiss() is what I need.